# How to scroll in nested tmux?

Tags: tmux

Sometimes, I have to use nested tmux session (tmux in tmux). Scrolling by copy-mode does not work in inner tmux session, so it makes me very inconvenient in inner session.

I heard there is meta-key to send tmux command to inner session. Any effective key bind to scroll in inner session?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130730/how-to-quickly-send-commands-to-nested-tmux-sessions may help

Answer (score 1):

`tmux copy-mode` will do it. Running the command will change to copy-mode in the inner session, and you can scroll as usual.

Another option is using `bind` and `send-prefix`, to bind some key to the `send-prefix` action, which sends the prefix to a nested session. In my case, it is:

```
set -g prefix C-a
bind a send-prefix
```

The default prefix is `C-b`, in that case it may be more reasonable to use `b`.

With that, you just Control+A (Or B or whatever) and then release Control and hit the same key again (A in my case, B seems better for people using the default `C-b` prefix, IMHO). That sends the prefix to the inner session. And now whatever you press will trigger a command in the inner session. i.e.: [Control+A] then [%] splits the window vertically for me. That's in the outer session, of course. Then with the `send-prefix` binding I mentioned, I can do [Control+A] then [A] then [%], and it splits the window in the inner session.

It's pretty nifty, useful for scrolling stuff, searching etc when connected to a server, and once you get used to it it becomes pretty much muscle-memory. Plus you can do [Ctrl+A] then [A] then [D] to detach the inner session, which will either let you `exit` an ssh connection or end the SSH connection entirely if you have a configuration that automaGically start tmux upon connecting.

And of course, you can bind `send-prefix` to some other key, possibly with `-n` so you can have something like [Ctrl+A] as the prefix and something like [Ctrl+S] to send the prefix to an inner session.

Comment: running copy-mode in the inner session does put the inner session into scroll mode, but scrolling with the mouse still causes the parent session to scroll instead. What's the trick?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too but realized my local `tmux.conf` was using vi keybindings for copy-mode and my remote (nested) session wasn't. You can use vi keybindings for both sessions by adding the following to your local and remote `tmux.conf`.

```
# Use vim keybindings in copy mode
setw -g mode-keys vi
```

Then either do `prefix + prefix + [` to enter copy-mode in the nested session and use vi keybindings to move around, or you could map a certain keystroke to send the prefix to the nested session by putting this in your local `tmux.conf`:

```
# Use Ctrl-a to send prefix to nested session
bind-key -n C-a send-prefix
```